# SAMLart How built it?

Tags: saml

Well, i have 2 apps(idp, sp) and I tried to communicate both for Artifact... but i don't  knowed how doing...
And I found googling this steps: http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02_html_19b6d40c.gif
but now i questioned...  how operate for this via (between step 4 to 5 with Java)?
What object i must build for pass this to SAMLart parameter?

Thanks for Advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Please post some code or an attempt that we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use this class in opensaml http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/opensaml/opensaml/2.4.1/opensaml-2.4.1-javadoc.jar!/org/opensaml/saml2/core/Artifact.html

My guess is that you use this one to send it to SP
http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/opensaml/opensaml/2.4.1/opensaml-2.4.1-javadoc.jar!/org/opensaml/saml2/binding/encoding/HTTPArtifactEncoder.html

Comment: do you have any code of how build the Artifact Object at sp app?

Comment: The artifact is sent and built at the IDP

Comment: Hi guys! yesterday i found that for build the SAMLart parameter I should start with the SAML2ArtifactBuilderFactory object.... Anyone have code (Java) about how build this?  Thanks for advance!

Comment: any person know about this?